# bosh-lite installation on openstack

Tags: openstack, cloud-foundry

I have already installed bosh-lite and cloud foundry on single VM using the tutorials at https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/deploying/run-local.html.  Is there a way to install the bosh-lite and cloud-foundry on OpenStack?

I searched a lot but could not find a proper answer, what I found is something disconnected like installing bosh and OpenStack on a single VM but I don't know if that can be useful to me.

I am pretty new to cloud-foundry and OpenStack so, the things are pretty confusing for me.  My ultimate goal is to deploy and test docker with cloud-foundry which means installing Diego, I could have used cf_nise_installer, but I am not sure if it supports Diego.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want everything deployed on a single VM, or do you want a real distributed deployment? Most documentation for OpenStack will focus on doing a distributed deployment.

Comment: I want a single VM version and as you said, I am only finding resources for  distributed deployment.

Comment: @AmitKumarGupta If everything is required in a single VM, do we actually need to install Bosh-Lite on VirtualBox on that VM or it can exist independently ?

Comment: @user3275095 Can you please help with updates on this, if any ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you want to deploy CF and Diego on a single VM on OpenStack.

- Why a single VM, could it be 2 or 3?
- Why OpenStack, why not AWS, or DigitalOcean, or something else?
- Do you need *all* the features of CF (multi-tenancy, service integration, buildpacks) or is Docker + Diego + Routing + Logging + a nice CLI sufficient, etc?

At any rate, there is no out-of-the-box solution for your exact set of requirements, but you have several options, with tradeoffs:

- Use local BOSH-Lite instead of OpenStack.  You can deploy Diego to your BOSH-Lite alongside your CF, and play around with the Docker support there.  See instructions here: https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/diego-release/#deploying-diego-to-bosh-lite
- Use Lattice.  Lattice is basically Diego, along with routing, log aggregation, and a CLI to make it easy to push Docker-based apps, scale them up and down, get logs, etc.  You will not get the full CF feature set, for instance there is no UAA which CF uses for user authentication, managing multi-tenancy, scopes and permissions, etc. You can check out the Lattice website: http://lattice.cf/.  Docs on deploying Lattice are here: http://lattice.cf/docs/terraform/.  You can see several deployment options there, including OpenStack if you search the page.

If you're willing to do *a lot* more work, you could either figure out how to make BOSH-Lite work against the OpenStack provider, or you could figure out enough about how BOSH manifests are structured and then use [bosh-init](https://bosh.io/docs/using-bosh-init.html) to deploy a single-VM deployment to OpenStack that colocates all of CF and Diego into a single "job".

Comment: Thanks for detailing. 
Why single VM: this is how the person above me wants it to be. Why OpenStack: because that is installed locally. I'll check lattice. I don't need all features, this is just for testing the apps  on CF.

I actually found [bosh-lite-openstack](https://github.com/starkandwayne/bosh-lite-openstack) and [vagrant-openstack-provider](https://github.com/ggiamarchi/vagrant-openstack-provider). I believe using these I can follow the usual installation of CF using bosh-lite.
Request your comment.

Comment: You can certainly give it a try, but there are some things to be aware of: it looks fairly old (last commit was 11 months ago), has only 1 star so may not have had a lot of use and ironing out of bugs, and even if it works it will give you a very old BOSH (e.g. it uses BOSH v124, the current version is v219).  You could open a GitHub issue against that repo to inquire about its status.  Regardless, you may want to try it anyways.

Comment: This might not make a difference, but just FYI, currently the way bosh-lite works is there's a pre-baked packer box, and `vagrant up` just creates a VM from that box with hardly any runtime provisioning.  On the other hand, bosh-lite-openstack uses a blank slate "dummy" box, and then provisions all the BOSH processes onto the VM at runtime (a.k.a. when running `vagrant up`).

Comment: Thanks Amit. I did check the versions and thought of replacing them with the what are used in bosh-lite installation locally tutorials. Anyways, currently I am  getting a failed VM on OpenStack and trying to investigate the issue.